# C# Archivo de Configuración - Aplicación externa

Tags: c#, archivo, configuración

Hola he hecho una aplicación que usa unas librerías externas.
Estas librerías externas tienen dos archivos de configuración.
Cuando ejecuto la aplicación funciona bien. Los archivos de configuración están en la misma carpeta del ejecutable y se lee sin problemas.
Pero yo necesito llamar desde otra aplicación a este ejecutable que usa esas librerías externas.
Cuando llamo al ejecutable, paece que el control se pasa a la aplicación desde la cual llamo al ejecutable, porque las linrerías externas intentan buscar los archivos de confgiuración desde la aplicación desde donde se llama y no desde el ejcutable que las referencia.
Yo había visto este comportamiento antes, no estoy eguro por qué sucede. Pero me preguntaba si se puede evitar, porque no puedo colocar esos archivos de configuración ahí.

Comment: si, capaz, cambiando el directorio de ejecucion de tu aplicacion que llama a la otra... todo eso, si podes cambiar el codigo de alguna....

Comment: Como dijo @gbianchi tienes que cambiar el directorio a la ejecución [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247192/change-the-working-directory-of-a-running-process-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema común, creo que todos hemos pasado por el. Las librerías siempre buscan los archivos de configuración en su contexto de ejecución. Piensa que el contexto es la aplicación que está corriendo, y esa tiene su propio fólder. Cuando inicializas otra librería en esa misma aplicación, se inicializa en ese mismo contexto, no en otro separado.

Lo mas sencillo es tener los archivos de configuración en la carpeta de ejecución, si tienen el mismo nombre que los de las librerías (app.config, web.config, config.json) no te preocupes, puedes juntar las llaves.

Como todo, hay otras maneras de solucionarlo, pero es mas importante seguir el principio KISS.